# c# Excel Interop, Identify when a column or line is inserted

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

Is there a way to identify whenever a column or line is inserted by the user, and get the address of the range?

Searching I only found it [Event when a row or column is inserted](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fce394e2-f40e-4ee7-86ad-e7cc49f58339/event-when-a-row-or-column-is-inserted-or-deleted-in-excel?forum=vsto)
in this forum they suggested to use the event 'Change'. it works, the problem is that Change Event is activated every time something happens to the Sheet cells, and I cannot identify what specifically happened, because of this it wouldn't fit in my case.

Comment: Have you thought of having an int variable and counting rows/columns? In difference to what the value of that variable was before. For Example: int countRows = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; If that variable decreases, it means a certain amount of Rows was deleted. If it increases, it means the opposite.

Comment: Good idea, the problem would be if the user write something in a cell out of the used range, so the range would grow, but if I use your solution with the event Change I may identify when a entire collumn or line is modified.

Comment: Perfect, happy coding!